# PHPStorm : Add file type to the 'new' dialog

Tags: phpstorm

I've just re-installed OS X and have forgotten how to add a file type to the `new` dialog (when you say right click within the project directory, select new and see list of different file types). I want to add Sass, which is currently not listed there. When I select `Edit file templates` it is there, but just not in the initial dialog.

Any idea?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Screenshots please (New menu and list of actual file templates) -- there could be few different reasons.

Comment: Screenshots now attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Stylesheet** entry in `New` menu -- there you can specify what file to create: CSS/Sass/SCSS/Less/Stylus.

Such grouping done on purpose -- to make `New` menu more compact as on some setups especially where user has quite few own templates it's way to big.

---

Alternative approach is to create your own Sass template instead of editing pre-defined entry. This way it will be listed as separate entry in `New` menu.

---

**To clarify things up:**

The default `Sass File` template (which you can edit) will be used if you choose `Stylesheet` entry in `New` menu. The logic is the same as with `PHP Trait` template -- it's not listed in `New` menu directly but accessible via `PHP Class` entry where you can choose what object (Class/Interface/Trait) to create.

Comment: It's really strange - I had to manually add another SCSS to the list of Code Templates to have it displayed - don't understand what's the purpose of having it listed in the settings, but not in the dialog.

Comment: Please read my answer again -- you seems to misread it completely (that's the impression I have from your comment). If you need clarification -- please ask specific question.

Comment: The default `Sass File` template (which you can edit) will be used if you choose `Stylesheet` in "New" menu. The logic is the same as with `PHP Trait` template -- it's not in "New" menu but accessible via "PHP Class" entry where you can choose what object (Class/Interface/Trait) to create

Comment: Oh I see - thanks @LazyOne - I knew I'll get it at some point :)