# How to customize 'new file' dropdown in WebStorm

Tags: ide, editor, webstorm

When I upgraded to WebStorm 2016.3 the SASS and SCSS file disappeared from the `new file` dropdown in the `project explorer`.

I can't find where to configure the content of that menu. `Preferences -> Editor -> File and Code Templates` only modifies the templates, not which are available in the menu.

I'm certain the setting is staring me in the face, nonetheless I cannot find it.

[image: new file dropdown - no SASS. SCSS option]

[image: file and code templates]

Comment: From what version have you upgraded? It has been like that for few years now... 1) http://stackoverflow.com/a/32923287/783119 2) http://stackoverflow.com/a/39569681/783119

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new SCSS file template in `Preferences | Editor | File and code templates` - new templates will appear in File/New menu. But note that new scss/sass files can be created via `File/New/Stylesheeet` - just choose '`SCSS File`' or '`Sass File`' as stylesheet kind

Answer (score 1):

It's on Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Menus and Toolbars -> Favorites View Popup Menu -> New. Then click an item to remove with the left button then click 'Remove" on the right.